# Elements with $ in the id can't be altered in jquery

Tags: jquery

I've got a generated file and some IDs contain $ characters. JQuery can't work with the element if it has a $ character in it. Anyway to go around this without changing the IDs?

Example:
https://jsfiddle.net/duLba02y/

```
<div id="test">This works.</div>
<div id="te$t">This doesn't</div>
<script>
   $("#test").hide();
   $("#te$t").hide();
</script>
```

Comment: Generally I would say that I't not a really good idea to include characters that need to be escaped in an `id` attribute. Is there some special considerations that require you to use these special characters?

Comment: The ID is generated by another program and my influence on the ID's is limited.

Comment: I understand. Just wanted to point out that without a specific need for these special characters, using them only complicates things and creates readability issues in the code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since `$` is a meta characters, use `\\` to escape it.

```
$("#te\\$t").hide();
```

[**Docs**](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/)

> To use any of the meta-characters ( such as  !"#$%&'()*+,./:;<=>?@[]^`{|}~ ) as a literal part of a name, it must be escaped with with two backslashes: \\.